# Java: Contains() method

Tags: java, algorithm, contains

Trying to implement `contains()` method without using built-in method `contains()`.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean containsCS(String str, CharSequence cs) {
    //char[] chs = str.toCharArray();
    boolean result = false;

    int i=0;
    while(i<str.length()) {
        int j=0;
        while(j<cs.length()) {
            if(NEED TO CHECK IF THERE IS AN INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS EXCEPTION) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
            if(str.charAt(i+j)==cs.charAt(j)) {
                result|=true; //result = false or true ->>>>> which is true.
                j++;
            } else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let's say:

```
String   str = "llpll"
Charsequence cs = "llo"
```

I want to make sure this method works properly in the above case where the `Charsequence` has one or more `char` to check but the `String` runs out length. How should I write the first `if` statement?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you missed a bit out? Looks like and infinite loop to me. Where's the increment of i ?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson You are right. I just fixed that in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it were me first thing I'd check is that the length of my char sequence was <= to the length of my string.

As soon as you chop that logic path out. 
If the lengths are equal you can just use == 
Then it would occur that if you chopped up str
into cs length parts, you could do a straight comparison there as well.

e.g str of TonyJ and search for a three character sequence would pile through

Ton
ony
nyJ

One loop, one if statement and a heck of a lot clearer.

Comment: That is a very clever solution. Thanks, Tony!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (i+cs.length() > str.length()){
   OUT OF BOUNDS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and using the [contains](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method therein.

Edit - For the reading impaired:
The linked method is **not** from java.lang.String or java.lang.Object

If you'd bother to actually look at the links, you would see that it is the Apache Commons-Lang API and the StringUtils.contains(...) method that I reference, which very clearly answers the question.

Comment: From the question: "...without using built-in method contains()".

Comment: And if you need to do it for homework, don't ask here.  Go to your TA.  They know what you need to get out of the lesson.  If you just need the code to do it, look at the source for the linked method.

Comment: From the API - it isn't built in.  It is **not** the String's `contains(...)` method.  It is, in fact, a static method on `StringUtils` provided by Apache in the Commons-Lang API.

Comment: @DMoses I'm just practicing my algorithm skills.

Comment: @Mike Well, I'm practicing for interviews and I doubt I'll be able to use that. Thanks though.

Comment: @Mike - Ah, I read "this" as the Java keyword. Still, if the poster can't use String.contains(), likely Apache StringUtils.contains() is also out of bounds.

Comment: @Dinky In that case, I might think through it with psuedo code and see if you can explain it to a live person around you.  That, or trial and error helped me the most.  Also, your code won't work even with the out of bounds check.

Comment: If I ever got asked a question about how to do this in an interview, I think I'd laugh as I walked away.

Comment: @Mike Looking at the source code for Apache Commons, they do use the String built in `indexOf`

Comment: @DMoses I'm absolutely certain they do.  They would have to do so to guard against an `IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException` much in the same way he will have to do for the same reason.  The question was to exclude java.lang.String.contains(...) with an implicit requirement for the use of java.lang.String.indexOf(...) and java.lang.String.length().

Comment: @Mike. I've been asked dumber ones.. :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson As have I.  I just get up, shake their hand(s), thank them for their time, and leave.  It never looks good when the questions you are asked during an interview are lifted straight out of a college text book.  They are also no more relevant at an interview than they were in the textbook...

Comment: Questions in textbooks aren't relevant? Heretic! :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your homework, which I suspect it is, then I suggest you take a look at the [API for the String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class to see what other methods are available to help find the location of one String within another.

Also consider looking at the source code for String to see how it implements it.

Comment: It's not for homework... I was just practicing for tech interviews and got stuck.

Comment: Ah ok, well, in that case, my recommendation still stands. If you are planning on getting a job in the Java industry then I recommend doing the Oracle Certified Java Programmer/Developer exams. It's a good way to give you a grasp of the fundamentals and the developer specifically helps you put them into practice. A lot of it doesn't stand much stead in the real world, e.g, I've never been highly dependant on knowing that a long is 64 bit, it'll also help you in your tech interviews where they mostly cover core Java. Check out FizzBuzz on google if you want to know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, James. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already know this, but it is in fact possible to see the actual source code of the built-in classes and methods. So I'd take a look there for a start. The String class is especially interesting, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Fiery. I have already checked and it implements the `indexOf()` method.